404 ошибка на всех страницах после переноса битрикса на новый хостинг и домен
Сайт перенес с хостинга бегета на виртуальную машину яндекса. сайт на всех страницах, включая главную прогружает шапку, подвал, но в контент части выдает 404 ошибку. в логах апачи все ок, ошибок нет.
пробовал удалять 404.php из корня, тогда выдает 500 ошибку. до этого сайт был на nginx
переносил посредствам restore.php
бекап файлов делал средствами битрикса, а бд пришлось с сервера скачивать бекап, так как стандартными средствами не удалось создать.
где искать проблему?
в админку тоже не пускает. ввожу логин и пароль, и значок загрузки бесконечно крутится

проблема была в базе данных. видимо, там, где-то домен прописывается.
сделал бекап базы данных средствами битрикса, и все заработало.
